# What is the general design ideas of read-compute-write thread-safe program based on it's single-threaded version?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, multiprocessing, openmp

Consider that the sequental version of the program already exists and implements a sequence of  "read-compute-write" operations on a single input file and other single output file. "Read" and "write" operations are performed by the 3rd-party library functions which are hard (but possible) to modify, while the "compute" function is performed by the program itself. Read-write library functions seems to be not thread-safe, since they operate with internal flags and internal memory buffers.

It was discovered that the program is CPU-bounded, and it is planned to improve the program by taking advantage of multiple CPUs (up to 80) by designing the multi-processor version of the program and using `OpenMP` for that purpose. The idea is to instantiate multiple "compute" functions with same single input and single output.

It is obvious that something nedds to be done in insuring the consistent access to reads, data transfers, computations and data storages. Possible solutions are: (hard) rewrite the IO library functions in thread-safe manner, (moderate) write a thread-safe wrapper for IO functions that would also serve as a data cacher.

Is there any general patterns that cover the subject of converting, wrapping or rewriting the single-threaded code to comply with `OpenMP` thread-safety assumptions?

EDIT1: The program is fresh enough for changes to make it multi-threaded (or, generally a parallel one, implemented either by multi-threading, multi-processing or other ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick response, if you are processing a single file and writing to another, with openMP its easy to convert the sequential version of the program to a multi-thread version without taking too much care about the IO part, provided that the compute algorithm itself can be parallelized.

This is true because usually the main thread, takes care of the IO. If this cannot be achieved because the chunks of data are too big to read at once, and the compute algorithm cannot process smaller chunks, you can use the openMP API to synchronize the IO in each thread. This does not mean that the whole application will stop or wait until the other threads finish computing so new data can be read or written, it means that only the read and write parts need to be done atomically.

For example, if the flow of your sequencial application is as follows:

```
1) Read
2) compute
3) Write
```

Given that it truly can be parallelized, and each chunk of data needs to be read from within each thread, each thread could follow the next design:

```
1) Synchronized read of chunk from input (only one thread at the time could execute this section)
2) Compute chunk of data (done in parallel)
3) Synchronized write of computed chunk to output (only one thread at the time could execute this section)
```

if you need to write the chunks in the same order you have read them, you need to buffer first, or adopt a different strategy like fseek to the correct position, but that really depends if the output file size is known from the start, ...

Take special attention to the openMP scheduling strategy, because the default may not be the best to your compute algorithm. And if you need to share results between threads, like the offset of the input file you have read, you may use reduction operations provided by the openMP API, which is way more efficient than making a single part of your code run atomically between all threads, just to update a global variable, openMP knows when its safe to write.

**EDIT:**

In regards of the "read, process, write" operation, as long as you keep each read and write atomic between every worker, I can't think any reason you'll find any trouble. Even when the data read is being stored in a internal buffer, having every worker accessing it atomically, that data is acquired in the exact same order. You only need to keep special attention when saving that chunk to the output file, because you don't know the order each worker will finish processing its attributed chunk, so, you could have a chunk ready to be saved that was read after others that are still being processed. You just need each worker to keep track of the position of each chunk and you can keep a list of pointers to chunks that need to be saved, until you have a sequence of finished chunks since the last one saved to the output file. Some additional care may need to be taken here.

If you are worried about the internal buffer itself (and keeping in mind I don't know the library you are talking about, so I can be wrong) if you make a request to some chunk of data, that internal buffer should only be modified after you requested that data and before the data is returned to you; and as you made that request atomically (meaning that every other worker will need to keep in line for its turn) when the next worker asks for his piece of data, that internal buffer should be in the same state as when the last worker received its chunk. Even in the case that the library particularly says it returns a pointer to a position of the internal buffer and not a copy of the chunk itself, you can make a copy to the worker's memory before releasing the lock on the whole atomic read operation.

If the pattern I suggested is followed correctly, I really don't think you would find any problem you wouldn't find in the same sequential version of the algorithm.

Comment: I'm afraid that IO needs synchronisation, since it operates with the internal buffer. Disk reads may be atomic, but buffer stores/retrieves are not - a request for disk read may come just between previous read and previous buffer transfer.

Comment: take a look to the edit, I could not respond everything here.

Answer (score 1):

with a little of synchronisation you can go even further.  Consider something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads
{
#pragma omp section
  {
    input();
    notify_read_complete();
  }
#pragma omp section
  {
    wait_read_complete();
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N)
    {
      do_compute_with_threads();
    }
    notify_compute_complete();
  }
#pragma omp section
  {
    wait_compute_complete();
    output();
  }
}
```

So, the basic idea would be that input() and output() read/write chunks of data.  The compute part then would work on a chunk of data while the other threads are reading/writing.  It will take a bit of manual synchronization work in notify*() and wait*(), but that's not magic.

Cheers,
        -michael